# Do SharePoint 2016 servers have to be members of the same domain as SQL Server (w/replication)?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server-2016

Scenario:

- The environment includes two domains, A and B.  Appropriate trusts have been configured between the domains.
- A 4 server SharePoint 2016 farm as been configured, each server is a member of domain A
- SQL server is configured for replication

We need to switch the domain membership for the 4 SharePoint servers to domain B, but we want to leave the SQL servers as members of domain A.  Even though the servers will be members of domain B, we are expecting to continue to use domain A service accounts.

Will there be any issues expected for a SharePoint farm where all servers are members of domain B, while the SQL servers (availability group/cluster) are members of domain A?

Comment: obligatory question: Why would you want to?

Comment: Path of least effort.  I'm told that reconfiguring SQL so that the servers are a member of domain B is a major effort.  We're intending to avoid that level of effort unless we can determine that it is absolutely necessary.